# Symfony 3 embedded forms labels not numbers

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to change those numbers (names of embedded forms) to some other labels (they depend on StatisticField's name property)  without using javascript?

[image]

StatisticType has StatisticFieldTypes:

```
$builder->add('statisticFields', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => StatisticFieldType::class,
            'by_reference' => true,
        ));
```

StatisticFieldType:

```
 $builder->add('dateSince', DateTimeType::class, [
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'label' => 'date.since',
                    'required' => false,

                ])
                    ->add('dateTo', DateTimeType::class, [
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'label' => 'date.to',
                        'required' => false,

                    ]);
```

Thanks.
**[EDIT_1]:**
My template:

```
<h1>Statistic creation</h1>
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Can you show us your twig template? I suspect those number comming from a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the twig, it looks ok. I think i found your problem and answered, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to override buildView method in StatisticFieldType (embedded form type) and get the data from the form :

```
   /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // For Symfony 2.1 and higher:
        $view->vars['label'] = $form->getData()->getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $builder->add('statisticFields', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => StatisticFieldType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
        'by_reference' => true,
    ));
```

The numbers came from `CollectionType`

EDIT:

With Names

```
    $name = 'IamNotANumber';


    $builder->add('statisticFields', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => StatisticFieldType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => $name),
        'by_reference' => true,
    ));
```

Comment: i want to have labels , but not numbers. Each StatisticField has its name

Comment: This code removed labels for collections, not the StatitisticField's labels

Comment: I want to have names instead those  0 , 1 , 2... numbers . I do not want to remove collection's names Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to get StatisticField instance and return its name through the callback function?